# Xcode stuck in opening icloud folder

Tags: xcode, icloud

I have a flutter project folder. Folder is in `icloud drive`. I am not able to open the folder in xcode. Opening folder get stuck. I am not able to create apk or build for ios.

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get 
flutter build apk
```

The first command tried to clean `Xcode` build before creating apk and it is stuck forever on this command.
When i try to download icloud folder it is also taking allot of time. In last one hour only 1% is download and i have 50MB download and 1GB upload speed.

I tried to download folder as individual folder but still it is taking forever.
Is it possible to open the icloud drive folder in xcode and create build or is there any faster way of download a folder from icloud. Please help